# Issue with looping through my linked list

Tags: c, operating-system

```
typedef struct node{
   unsigned int base_address;       
   unsigned int limit_offset;       
   struct node *next;               
   struct node *previous;           
}node;
```

This is the code I used to make a node and this is the loop

```
void sort_by_id(node *listHead){
    while(listHead->next != 0){
        node current = *listHead;
        node search = current;
        node lowest = current;
        while(search.next != 0){
            if(search.base_address<lowest.base_address){
                lowest = search;
            }
            search = search->next;
        }
        node temp = lowest;
        search = current;
        if(current.base_address == listHead->base_address){
            lowest.next = search.next;
            lowest.previous = search.previous;
            search.next = temp.next;
            search.previous = temp.previous;
            *listHead = lowest;
        }else{
            lowest.next = search.next;
            lowest.previous = search.previous;
            search.next = temp.next;
            search.previous = temp.previous;
        }
        current= current->next;
    }
}
```

currently in this state its giving me an error saying that in lines `search = search->next;` & `current= current->next;` '->' is an invalid argument type. I am new to c and any help would be appreciated.

I've tried changing the two troubled lines to `search = search.next*;` and `current= current.next*;` respectively but then I get an error telling me "expected expression before ';' token. so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: I believe `node current = *listHead;` should be `node *current = listHead;`. The next two lines should probably also have an `*` added to them, to make them pointers. However, after making those changes, you will have to use `->` instead of `.` in a few places.

Comment: `search` is a `node`, not a pointer. `search->next` is a pointer. You can't assign them.

Comment: You seem to be trying random changes to the code, they're not even valid syntax. You need to slow down, take a breath, and think about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

`sort_by_id()` appears to be selection sort so just reimplemented it (your code didn't compile as you mixed up pointers and objects).  The only interesting thing here is that `swap()` only manipulates the data elements and leaves the pointers alone.  You could manipulate pointers and leave the data elements but that is more work (4 pointers in the two nodes you are swapping, and 1 of pointers in the 4 nodes before/after each of those 2 nodes for a total of 8 pointers).

I also wrote you a `build()`, `print()` and some test data to demonstrate it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    unsigned base_address;
    unsigned limit_offset;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
}node;

void swap(node *a, node *b) {
    if(a == b) return;
    unsigned base_address = a->base_address;
    unsigned limit_offset = a->limit_offset;
    a->base_address = b->base_address;
    a->limit_offset = b->limit_offset;
    b->base_address = base_address;
    b->limit_offset = limit_offset;
}

// selelection sort
void sort_by_id(node *listHead){
    for(; listHead && listHead->next; listHead = listHead->next) {
        node *min = listHead;
        for(node *listHead2 = listHead->next; listHead2; listHead2 = listHead2->next)
            if(listHead2->base_address < min->base_address)
                min = listHead2;
        swap(min, listHead);
    }
}

struct node *build(unsigned n, unsigned addrs[n]) {
    node *nodes = malloc(sizeof(node) * n);
    if(!nodes)
        return NULL;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        nodes[i].base_address = addrs[i];
        // TODO: nodes[i].limit_offset = ...
        nodes[i].next = i + 1 < n ? &nodes[i+1] : NULL;
        nodes[i].previous = i ? &nodes[i-1] : NULL;
    }
    return nodes;
}

void print(node *head) {
    for(; head; head = head->next)
        printf("%d%s", head->base_address, head->next ? " " : "\n");
}

int main() {
    node *head = build(5, (unsigned []) {1, 0, 2, 4, 3});
    print(head);
    sort_by_id(head);
    print(head);
}
```

and example session:

```
1 0 2 4 3
0 1 2 3 4
```